# Adding a node to svg element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an svg element that is a 64 square board. You can see the structure below:

[image: Current svg]

The board is from a git repository.

It is rendered in my react app using `<Paper id="board"></Paper>` and the instance of the board is using the following code:

```
      board.current = new Chessboard(document.getElementById('board'), {
        position: chess.fen(),
        sprite: {
          url: './chessboard-sprite.svg', /
          grid: 40, 
          cache: true,
        },
        orientation: COLOR.white,
        moveInputMode: MOVE_INPUT_MODE.dragPiece,
        responsive: true,
      });

      fenHistory.push(chess.fen());
    
      board.current.enableMoveInput(inputHandler);
```

I would like to add another `<g class="pieces"></g>` so that it is the last g class. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you edit the `Chessboard` class? That's presumably what makes the `<g>`s and where you could add another.

Answer (score 1):

I used insertAdjacentHTML in the end. This let me put a new <g...> in as a child element to the .